# Create cursor when hover on cell

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, project-online

I tried this code to change style of the cell on jsgrid:

```
JsGridControlInstance.parentNode.jsgridparams.styleManager.RegisterCellStyle("Important", SP.JsGrid.Style.CreateStyle(SP.JsGrid.Style.Type.Cell, { textColor: "#4169E1", textAlign: 'left', fontWeight:"bold"}));
```

I wonder if it is possible to create a cursor when hovering on the cell?

Comment: "cursor: pointer;" in the CSS part doesn't work?